# When fetching data with Observable, need to use detector.detectChanges Angular v6+

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, two-way-binding

I have a weird bug in my angular project. When I fetch my data with a mock API from local data, everything is working fine, but when I switch to Online API and fetch data with `Observable` subscribe method, data is not updated in my angular template view. It will be updated only when I call `detector.detectChanges()` method.

**In brief,** For somehow when using online API, two-way data binding is only working when I call `detectChanges`.

For example imagine below scenario:

```
 data = [some data here...]
 getData(): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.data);
}
```

when I call this method in my `.ts` file and fetch data with it, angular template will be updated automatically. But when i switch to below code:

```
getData(): Observable<any> {
    let url = `${this.API_URL}/fetchData/`;
    return this.http.get(url);
}
```

and fetch data in my angular `.ts` file like below:

```
this.myService.getData().subscribe(result => {
    this.myData = result;
    // this.detector.detectChanges();
})
```

`myData` variable is not updated in the angular template unless I uncomment `// this.detector.detectChanges()` method.

And `detectChanges` is imported from below library of angular:

```
private detector: ChangeDetectorRef,
```

Can anyone help me please to overcome this bug? It's really annoying and my code now has a lot of `detectChanges` everywhere right after any code that needs two-way data binding!

thanks in advance

### Update

my .html file

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive"
                           style="display: inline-table;">
                        <thead>
                        <tr style="left: 0;">
                            <th><span>test</span></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr style="left: 0;" *ngFor="let d of myData">
                               <td>{{d.test}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Why not set `this.myService.getData()` directly to `this.myData`, making it an `Observable`, and use `async` pipe on it (e.g. `myData | async`) in the template?

Comment: can you explain with more details and maybe in answer section. I really appreciate any help ;)

Comment: Can you show us your template (.html) first?

Comment: it's normal html. I update a section of it.

Comment: Can you show the entire component file. What change detection strategy are you using?

Comment: the problem is two-way data binding is not working properly. Seem like after fetching data with Observable, the variable is not updated and the angular template doesn't understand changes. I should call `detector.detectChanges()` method so Angular knows that the variable is updated.

Comment: Try this:  this.myData = [...result];

Comment: check there is a `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your `@Component` decorator config. Delete it, if you want angular CD to dirty checking for you after something async event happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the comments I don't like to do the async in the HTML, I do it the same way you have coded above.  My questions are what is your `ChangeDetectionStrategy`set to on the component.  Some of them will not auto notice changes and update the UI (which could explain your issue).

This is because, in `app.component.ts` of the template, it's using `changeDetectionStrategy.onPush` so basically whenever anything in angular context happens, I should use commands like `detector.detectChanges()`.
Simply by using `changeDetectionStrategy.Default` everything will be normal and angular two-way binding will work fine.

Comment: Yap, I think he set the Strategy to OnPush.

Comment: I was using metronic opensource template. seems like it was on `ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush`. Now that i changed it to `Default` everything seems to work fine. I guess just by changing that all my problems are solved. Am i Right?

Comment: When you use OnPush detect changes is triggered by either input changes, events fired , using | async in the template or manually calling detect changes or markForCheck, with OnPush you will get the best performance, but you have to get use to have in mind those 4 things when you code

Comment: thanks. problems solved appreciate. I also updated your answer